# Puppet recurse attribute for file resource when creating non-directory/normal files

Tags: puppet

If I want:

```
file { '/var/shennanigans/happy-hour.drunk':
    ensure => present,
    mode => 700,
    owner => shamus
}
```

Can I use recurse => true to ensure the shennanigans directory exists or do I need to create a separate resource with an ensure => directory?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to declare two file resources, one for the directory, and one for the file, using dependencies to ensure that the file isn't placed before the directory has been created, like so:

```
file { '/var/shennanigans':
  ensure  => directory,
  purge   => true,
  recurse => true,
  owner   => 'seamus',
}

file { '/var/shennanigans/happy-hour.drunk':
  ensure  => present,
  mode    => 0700,
  owner   => 'seamus',
  require => File['/var/shennanigans'],
}
```

Note that the `mode` parameter should use a four-digit octal notation rather than three-digits - [see Puppet Type docs](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/latest/type.html#file-attribute-mode).

Btw I've corrected your owner's name ;)

Comment: Is that the only spelling for that Irish name?

Comment: O/T, but yes, it's the accepted spelling of the Gaelic name, often missing the accent on the 'e': http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S%C3%A9amus

Comment: Starting with Puppet 2.7 you don't *need* to set the require since it will auto-require all parent nodes (http://projects.puppetlabs.com/issues/6368)

Comment: @faker - thanks, valid point :) However I always tend to err on the side of caution and verboseness, if anything to make it clearer if files are spread across multiple modules/subclasses.